# sql injection vulnerabilities in empty and isset checks

Tags: php, sql

i am currently working on making my site injection proof and was wondering about the validations i am making, my code goes like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['street'])){
  $city = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']));
  $street = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['street']));   
}
```

my question is isnt the empty check itself is a vulnerability? 
i mean do i have to escape string in the !empty validation as well? or it is safe to keep it that way?
thanks.

Comment: There is no use `htmlentities`; and no, `empty` is not vulnerable, no need for escaping there

Comment: It's fine. Learn about what an injection vulnerability actually is: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/). Also, why you're escaping too much.

Comment: htmlentities is redundant, if you keep worrying about the sql injection, just go to following URL. it has been asked and get the high rate answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

For SQL injection you only need to worry when quering the database, so isset is safe.

There should be no need for `htmlentities` (use it as protection against XSS).

`mysql_real_escape_string` will protect against SQL injection [if done correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string), **but should not be used at all, since the mysql_ prefix / DB-handler is outdated, deprecated and should not be used at all**.
The safest way is to use either [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

SQL injection vulnerabilities work like this:

```
$username = $_GET["username"];

mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" . $username . "'");
```

Now if the value of `$_GET["username"]` is something like `"foo' OR 1=1--"`

The query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'foo' OR 1=1
--'
```

will be run which selects all users

If you escape your input you will get the (intended) query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'foo\' OR 1=1--'
```

PHP functions themselves aren't vulnerable.

---

Maybe this a good analogy: when someone says *"Say your name"* they want you to say *"I'm John"* not *"your name"*

Comment: A typo - in your example it will drop the table not the database :)

Comment: This is a bad example because `mysql_query` will not execute multiple queries in one string by default.